# Jenkins server crashes while building maven project

Tags: maven, jenkins, build, jar, crash

After the `clean install package` Maven build is triggered it takes no more than 15-20 seconds for the job to freeze. If I refresh the page it shows "This site can’t be reached". In order to make it work again I have to manually restart it from the Ubuntu Server. The logs don't show any building exceptions that would shutdown Jenkins. I also increased the heap size of Jenkins to 512M within `etc/default/jenkins`.

Configuration:

- Spring Boot project hosted on GitLab
- GitLab is integrated with Jenkins CI (it works fine and starts build on a new push on master)
- Jenkins is hosted on a Digital Ocean droplet running on Ubuntu OS with 1GB RAM

Comment: Please, post Jenkins logs.

Comment: 512MB is extremely low for Jenkins. They [recommend a minimum of at least 2GB](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/admin-resources/latest/jvm-troubleshooting/)

Comment: First sorry to say that but you have to learn how Maven works because using `clean install package` this runs a lot of step double... you should use `mvn clean verify` instead. The other question is if `install` is really needed? Furthermore really running Jenkins with 512M is too low... You should have more RAM... I recommend to use a larger machine setup depending on how much you are using it I would suggest to start with 2 G of RAM (maybe 1 G might work?)...

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue, my project crashed after

```
clean install package
```

but increasing the ram from `1GB` to `4GB` solved my issue

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).